# Querying MongoDB array with Aggregator function: Achieving desired output?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

For my problem i have below sample database record & in output need to develop result as mentioned in output desk. data. I am very new to mongoDb but trying `$match`, `$aggregator`, `$projection` to develop expected result. Any suggestion help would be really appreciated

```json
  {
    "_id": "act_8347100017075469",
    "firstName": "Akki",
    "lastName": "Dlast",
    "accountNumber": "12397124",
    "feature": {
      "feature-name1": {
        "baseCode": "bc1",
        "serviceCode": [
          //numb of elements & name of elements in servicesCodes are dynamic
          "SC1",
          "SC2",
          "SC3"
        ]
      },
      "feature-name2": {
        "baseCode": "bc2",
        "serviceCode": [
          //numb of elements & name of elements in servicesCodes are dynamic
          "SC21",
          "SC22"
        ]
      },
      "feature-name3": {
        "baseCode": "bc3",
        "serviceCode": [
          "SC41",
          "SC42",
          "SC43"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

output

```
Account No  feature-name,  base-code,  svc-code
12397124,   feature-name1,  bc1,          SC1
12397124,   feature-name1,  bc1,          SC1 
12397124,   feature-name1,  bc1,          SC3
12397124,   feature-name2,  bc2,          SC21
12397124,   feature-name2   bc2,          SC21 
12397124,   feature-name3,  bc3,          SC41
12397124,   feature-name3   bc3,          SC42 
12397124,   feature-name3,  bc3,          SC43
```

Attempt at aggregation pipeline ([mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VvADlWCRSU-)):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "feature.feature-name1.baseCode": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      accountNbr: 1,
      "feature": "feature-name1",
      "baseCode": "$feature.feature-name1.baseCode"
    }
  }
])
```

... but this only returns part of the required output.

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "act_8347100017075469",
    "baseCode": "bc1",
    "feature": "feature-name1"
  }
]
```

Comment: Are `"feature-nameX"` dynamic?  I.e., are there always these three?  FYI, it's generally considered an _anti-pattern_ to use any data as field names in MongoDB.  Using data as field names almost always leads to more complicated and less performant queries.

Comment: Do you need a single output for the entire collection, i.e, all `"accountNumber"`'s?

Comment: What queries have you tried so far?  How are those queries inadequate?  Please show your attempted aggregation pipelines.

Comment: @rickhg12hs feature-namesX are fixed for now...there are 3 values only , yes single output ...i need to run it on one collection & get all the extracted data.  ... i am new to mongo so i was learning & so far got to get only one query..         
db.collection.aggregate( [ { $match : { "feature.feature-name1.baseCode" : { $exists: true } } }, 
{ $project : { accountNbr : 1 , "feature":"feature-name1", "baseCode": "$feature.feature-name1.baseCode" } } 
] );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "feature": {
        "$objectToArray": "$feature"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$feature"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$feature.v.serviceCode"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "accountNumber": 1,
      "feature.k": 1,
      "feature.v.baseCode": 1,
      "feature.v.serviceCode": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "Account No": "$accountNumber",
      "feature-name": "$feature.k",
      "base-code": "$feature.v.baseCode",
      "svc-code": "$feature.v.serviceCode"
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sNxPX6hvCZ4).

Comment: Thanks a ton..it really helped. With this, i am able to create similar query for another requirement as well.
i made small change, my mongo version is 4.0 so $set did not work... i had replaced it with $addFields ...as per some research & https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/....it is giving correct result so far.....Thanks again

Comment: @Gagd If you find this answer useful, you can show other readers by accepting it and/or upvoting it.

Comment: i have accepted the answer but i dont have enough points to upvote. Once again thanks.